# XSLT transforming string with dot separated characters

Tags: xslt-2.0

I'm using a XSLT to transform an XML.
I want to split the characters of the node `initials` with dot's:

The following things i need to change for `initials` :

1. Every characters splitted by a dot
2. Capitalize every char
3. Remove spaces

I can't find a way to split the characters and insert DOTS if they don't exist.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jsonObject>
    <account>
        <initials>ABC</initials>
    </account>
    <account>
        <initials>A BC</initials>
    </account>
    <account>
        <initials>A.B.C  </initials>
    </account>
    <account>
        <initials>a.B.C</initials>
    </account>
</jsonObject>
```

I want the following output after transformation:

```
<results>
   <account>
      <field name="initials">A.B.C</field>
   </account>
   <account>
      <field name="initials">A.B.C</field>
   </account>
   <account>
      <field name="initials">A.B.C</field>
   </account>
   <account>
      <field name="initials">A.B.C</field>
   </account>
</results>
```

my stylesheet so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <results>
            <xsl:for-each select="account">
                <account>
                    <field name="initials"><xsl:value-of select="upper-case(translate(initials, ' ',''))"/></field>
                </account>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </results>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use RegEx'es to fn:replace every character with the character itself followed by a dot:

1. First, remove all other characters with `translate`:

   ```
   translate(.,' .,','')
   ```
2. Second, turn all characters to upper case:

   ```
   upper-case(.)
   ```
3. Replace every character with itself followed by a dot:

   ```
   replace(.,'(.)','$1.'))
   ```
4. Remove leading and trailing spaces:

   ```
   normalize-space(.)
   ```
5. Remove the last dot:

   ```
   replace(.,'\.$','')
   ```

This is the XSLT-2.0 code:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <results>
            <xsl:for-each select="account">
                <account>
                    <field name="initials"><xsl:value-of select="replace(normalize-space(replace(upper-case(translate(.,' .,','')),'(.)','$1.')),'\.$','')"/></field>
                </account>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </results>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

i found a solution:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:functx="http://www.functx.com"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:function name="functx:chars" as="xs:string*" xmlns:functx="http://www.functx.com">
        <xsl:param name="arg" as="xs:string?"/>

        <xsl:sequence select="
            for $ch in string-to-codepoints($arg)
            return codepoints-to-string($ch)
            "/>

    </xsl:function>

    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <results>
            <xsl:for-each select="account">
                <account>
                    <field name="initials"><xsl:value-of select="string-join(functx:chars(upper-case(translate(translate(initials, '.',''), ' ',''))), '.')"/></field>                    
                </account>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </results>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

In XSLT 3.0 you could use the `analyze-string` function:

```
  <xsl:template match="initials">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:value-of
            select="analyze-string(., '\p{L}')/*:match => string-join('.') => upper-case()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pPJ9hE3

Or you could use the XSLT 2/3 `xsl:analyze-string` element in a function similar to your approach:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
    xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="2.0">


  <xsl:function name="mf:analyze">
      <xsl:param name="input" as="xs:string"/>
      <xsl:param name="regex" as="xs:string"/>
      <xsl:analyze-string select="$input" regex="{$regex}">
          <xsl:matching-substring>
              <fn:match>
                  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
              </fn:match>
          </xsl:matching-substring>
      </xsl:analyze-string>
  </xsl:function>

  <xsl:template match="initials">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:value-of
            select="upper-case(
                      string-join(
                         mf:analyze(., '\p{L}'),
                         '.'
                      )
                    )"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```